# Mock RestTemplate.exchange using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, junit5

Here is my code that I want to mock.

```
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put(LOGIN_ID, loginId);
    params.put(LOGIN_PWD, loginPwd);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(params, headers);
    ResponseEntity<HashMap> omsResponse = restTemplate.exchange(loginUrl, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, HashMap.class);
```

Here is the test I am running.

```
    PromotionDto promotionDto = getPromotionDto();
    ResponseEntity<HashMap> omsResponse = new ResponseEntity<>(new HashMap(), HttpStatus.OK);
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(params, headers);
    String loginUrl = "https://dev.example.com/smcfs/restapi/invoke/login";
    Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(loginUrl, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, HashMap.class)).thenReturn(omsResponse);
    OrderCaptureOMSResponse response = omsService.orderCapture(promotionDto, IS_EMPLOYEE);
```

The error I am getting

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.PotentialStubbingProblem:
```

Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check:

- this invocation of 'exchange' method:
  restTemplate.exchange(
  null,
  POST,
  <{LoginID=null, Password=null},[Content-Type:"application/json"]>,
  class java.util.HashMap
  );
  -> at com.qurateretail.order.promotion.service.OmsServiceImpl.omsInterfaceLogin(OmsServiceImpl.java:87)
- has following stubbing(s) with different arguments:

  1. restTemplate.exchange(
     "https://dev.example.com/smcfs/restapi/invoke/login",
     POST,
     <{},[]>,
     class java.util.HashMap
     );
     -> at com.qurateretail.order.promotion.service.OmsServiceTest.orderCaptureTest(OmsServiceTest.java:40)
     Typically, stubbing argument mismatch indicates user mistake when writi

Answer (score 0):

When copying your code and running it myself it worked fine when using correctly ;).

```
ResponseEntity<HashMap> omsResponse = new ResponseEntity<>(new HashMap(), 
HttpStatus.OK);
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(params, headers);
String loginUrl = "https://dev.example.com/smcfs/restapi/invoke/login";
Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(loginUrl, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, HashMap.class)).thenReturn(omsResponse);

ResponseEntity<HashMap> exchange = restTemplate.exchange(loginUrl, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, HashMap.class);
System.out.println(exchange);
```

From the error Message

```
his invocation of 'exchange' method: restTemplate.exchange( null, POST, 
<{LoginID=null, Password=null},[Content-Type:"application/json"]>, class 
java.util.HashMap );
```

you can see that in your Code the parameter "loginUrl" is different then what you are mocking. In your Mock it mocks "https://dev.example.com/smcfs/restapi/invoke/login" as loginUrl. In your actual execution the code has null for the URL. The Mock only works if the Mock and the call of that method has the exact same parameters. Why your loginUrl is null is something i can not say with the Code you provided. The relevant parts for that are missing ^^.

Another approach would be to generalize the mock.

```
Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(any(), ...
```

this is however a bit tricky with restTemplate since the method Overloading of "exchange" make it difficult. Matching the arguments is better anyways.

Comment: I tried matching the argument for loginURL as null and here is the new error

`Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(null, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, HashMap.class)).thenReturn(omsResponse);
`

Comment: `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.PotentialStubbingProblem: 
Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check:
 - this invocation of 'exchange' method:
    restTemplate.exchange(
    null,
    POST,
    <{LoginID=null, Password=null},[Content-Type:"application/json"]>,
    class java.util.HashMap
);
    -> at com.qurateretail.order.promotion.service.OmsServiceImpl.omsInterfaceLogin(OmsServiceImpl.java:87)
 - has following stubbing(s) with different arguments:
    1. restTemplate.exchange(
    null,
    POST,
    <{},[]>,
    class java.util.HashMap
);`